# Railstutorial.org Chapter 8: digest method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm currently working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and I found a method definition I don't quite get:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

The crucial part is the definiton of `User.digest` ... why does he write `def User.digest(string)` and not just `def digest(string)` ...

We are in the User class so every method in it should be accessible by `User.<method_name>`. So isn't it redundant or wrong to define a method like this?

Comment: `def User.digest` ≡ `def self.digest` ≡ `class << self ; def digest ... end` is a declaration of class method. `def digest` is a declaration of an instance method, that is to be called on instances: `User.new.digest` rather on the class itself: `User.digest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `def digest(string)`, you are actually defining an **instance** method.

Read more about class and instance methods here: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Michael Hartl actually explains why he defined the **class** method this way at the bottom (Section 8.6 point 1).

> ...we defined the new token and digest class methods by explicitly prefixing them with User. This works fine and, because they are actually called using User.new_token and User.digest, it is probably the clearest way to define them....

The other alternatives to define User class methods are:

```
def self.digest(string)
  #your code here
end
```

or

```
class << self
  def digest(string)
    #your code here
  end
end
```

Hope this helps! I also learned Rails using his book :)

Comment: thats a great and especially friendly answer :) thank you.. usually you feel so stupid asking such a basic stuff here :D

Answer (score 1):

Followings are **class methods** which are equivalent to each other:

```
def User.digest(string)
  # MY LOGIC
end

def self.digest(string)
  # MY LOGIC
end
```

Class methods got called directly on class like `User.digest("my_string")`.

> We are in the User class so every method in it should be accessible by User.

Unfortunately, this is **NOT** true. Only class methods will get called using `User.<method_name>`.

If you have defined a method

```
def digest(string)
  # MY LOGIC
end
```

Above is an **instance method** and will  get called on the instance (object) of `User` class (NOT directly on class) like:

```
user = User.new
user.digest("string")
```